# SQL - Counting column categories

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am new to SQL, but I am trying to create a report where I can count the food purchases made by students and categorized by the Race/Ethnicity and choice of food every year.

For Example:

```
         2012                                          2013
Student Vegetarian     Meat           Unknown          Vegetarian     Meat           Unknown
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Black    5 Purchases   4 Purchases      3 Purchases      5 Purchases   etc
White    4 Purchases   3 Purchases      3 Purchases      etc           etc
Asian    4 Purchases   1 Purchases      6 Purchases      etc           etc
```

While I was able to get the races in one column, I am lost at getting the count on different food categories. All I know is that the pur_type is classified as "Veg", "Me" and "Ukt" for Vegetarian, Meat and unknown purchase.

Here is what I tried to do:

```
select 
     DATEPART(YYYY,pur_date) AS Year
    ,count (*) Citations
    , race
    , sex
    , ethnicity
    , GETDATE() as YTD
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN pur_type = 'Veg' THEN 'Vegetarian' 
    WHEN pur_type = 'Me' THEN 'Meat' 
    WHEN pur_type  = 'UKt' THEN 'Unknown'  

         ELSE ''

         End as "Type"

, CASE 
    WHEN race='W' and sex='M' and ethnicity <> 'H' THEN 'Caucasian(Male)' 
    WHEN race='W' and sex='F' and ethnicity <> 'H' THEN 'Caucasian(Female)' 
    WHEN race='B' and sex='M' and ethnicity <> 'H' THEN 'African-American(Male)' 
    WHEN race='B' and sex='F' and ethnicity <> 'H' THEN 'African-American(Female)' 
    --WHEN race='A' and sex='M' and ethnicity <> 'H' THEN 'Pacific Islander(Male)' 
    --WHEN race='A' and sex='F' and ethnicity <> 'H' THEN 'Pacific Islander(Female)' 
    WHEN race='A' and sex='M' and ethnicity <> 'H' THEN 'Asian(Male)'  
    WHEN race='A' and sex='F' and ethnicity <> 'H' THEN 'Asian(Female)' 



    ELSE '' 
END as 'Race' 




from purchase
join purcharge
on purchase.purchaseid = purcharge.purchaseid
where pur_date between @startDate and  dateadd(DD, +1,  GETDATE())
and pur_type in ('Veg', 'Me', 'UKt')
GROUP BY DATEPART(YYYY,pur_date), race, sex, ethnicity , pur_type
ORDER BY 'Year','Race/Sex'
```

Looking for guidance. I am thinking maybe a sub query would work, maybe more case statements, but I am not able to have a count of how many food categories were purchased by students in each ethnic group.

Also,I am trying to get these results in an SSRS report so it may look slightly different in a SQL query.

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL server

Comment: Then tag your question with `SQL Server` tag.  `SQL` is just a language used by multiple dbms vendors.

Comment: Ok, I got it corrected.

Comment: @Eric Dude, it's a SQL query question.  Tagging it Sql Server just tells us the platform.

Comment: @Aerik You think the query above will work when you run it on `MySQL`?  Also it's useless if someone post Oracle query while OP use SQL Server.

Comment: @Eric Well... I'm pretty sure that DATEPART isn't valid in MySQL, so a MySQL guy would probably pick that out.  Pretty sure the rest of it would work, but it's been a long time since I worked in MySQL, and  I have no experience in Oracle.  But I think my main, knee jerk, reaction was to "SQL is *just* a language".  Certainly adding the platform he's on is helpful, the same as a javascript question is best frames in terms of what browsers are targeted, but your (second) comment kind of had a "jump on the guy" sort of tone that seems unnecessary.

Comment: poopiepoops, can you show a sample of your data as it is in the database table(s). Also what version of SQL Server are you using as that might have a bearing on the simplest answer.

Comment: @Alan, Sorry this is a sensitive data and I am not allowed to let it out. I use SQL server 2008 R2

Comment: I've posted an answer anyway. If people ask for sample data they will expect it to be fake, that's fine, but showing some dummy data and the expected output if that dummy data was real is just as useful as the real data. In fact it's often easier for others to understand. Anyway, if my answer does not help, Try showing some dummy data and expected output and we'll find a solution.You only need to end up with a simple thin table that SSRS can pivot using a Matrix so I think you were on the right lines.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into the [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) statement but if it was me, I'd do more CASE...WHEN and then GROUP BY.

So, instead of

`COUNT(CASE WHEN pur_type = 'Veg' THEN 'Vegetarian' (etc) AS Type`

I'd do

`SUM(CASE WHEN pur_type = 'Veg' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS Vegetarian`

etc.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really the best way to create a report, but if you need to use SQL (as opposed to having another layer of code to generate the report from a bunch of subsets of data), you could use subqueries. Without seeing the table structure, it is hard to write the query, but it could be something like this:

```
Select
    race
    , (select count(*) from purchase where pur_type = 'Veg' and race = race) as Vegetables
    , (select count(*) from purchase where pur_type = 'Me' and race = race) as Meat
    , (select count(*) from purchase where pur_type = 'UKt' and race = race) as Unknown
From purchase
```

Like I said, this isn't ideal, but it would get your the distinct subsets of data.

Comment: How would I use this in my scenario, where I have already dedicated the case statements, combining race sex and ethnicity? I'd like to create Data Fields for the SSRS report so I can choose them directly to fetch data.

Comment: For some reason, count(*) is not aggregating all instances of food category purchases. Shows the resuts as 0

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your data looks like and havn't got time to build sample data but I think you've actually just got a typo or two..

```
SELECT 
     DATEPART(YYYY,pur_date) AS [Year]
    ,count (*) Citations
    , race
    , sex
    , ethnicity
    , GETDATE() as YTD
    , COUNT(*) AS [PurchaseCount]
    , CASE 
        WHEN pur_type = 'Veg' THEN 'Vegetarian'
        WHEN pur_type = 'Me' THEN 'Meat'
        WHEN pur_type  = 'UKt' THEN 'Unknown'
        ELSE ''
    End as [Type]
, CASE 
    WHEN race='W' and sex='M' and ethnicity <> 'H' THEN 'Caucasian(Male)' 
    WHEN race='W' and sex='F' and ethnicity <> 'H' THEN 'Caucasian(Female)' 
    WHEN race='B' and sex='M' and ethnicity <> 'H' THEN 'African-American(Male)' 
    WHEN race='B' and sex='F' and ethnicity <> 'H' THEN 'African-American(Female)' 
    --WHEN race='A' and sex='M' and ethnicity <> 'H' THEN 'Pacific Islander(Male)' 
    --WHEN race='A' and sex='F' and ethnicity <> 'H' THEN 'Pacific Islander(Female)' 
    WHEN race='A' and sex='M' and ethnicity <> 'H' THEN 'Asian(Male)'  
    WHEN race='A' and sex='F' and ethnicity <> 'H' THEN 'Asian(Female)' 
    ELSE '' 
END as [Race] 
FROM purchase
JOIN purcharge
    ON purchase.purchaseid = purcharge.purchaseid
WHERE pur_date BETWEEN @startDate AND dateadd(DD, +1,  GETDATE())
    AND pur_type in ('Veg', 'Me', 'UKt')
GROUP BY DATEPART(YYYY,pur_date), race, sex, ethnicity , pur_type
ORDER BY [Year],[Race], [Type]
```

This will not give exactl what you asked for as it includes both race and gender in your [Race] case statement but maybe that's what you really wanted, I don't know...

Anyway, all I really changed was the count(*) as [PurchaseCount] , the following line's CASE statement and the GROUP BY clause. `COUNT(*)` will just give you the count of records that fall within your  `GROUP BY` clause. In this case a count of records for every [Year], [Race] and [Type]

Comment: Alan, thank you. This query does not give me the three fields that I require for the SSRS report. I would like to have Veg, Meat and Unknown as the variables/fields that can display the data. In theory, it should count all the incidents of purchases of Vegetarian, Mean and Unknown food categories purchased by a student in a given year. 

I tried one of the answers posted by another person here and it does create those fields/categories for the reort, but does not count the total number of each.

, (select count(*) from purchase where pur_type = 'Veg' and race = race) as Vegetables

Comment: Your SSRS report will do that work for you. If your original design is all you need, then you just need your results to contain, Race, Type, Year and count. In SSRS just add the above as your dataset. Add a Matrix to the report, set the row group to be Race and add column groups, one for year and then one for Type and finally drop the count column into the data values area. SSRS will basically do the rest of the work for you, there is not need for your SQL code to do the pivot type operation that you are trying to do. It's midnight here but if I get chance I'll post a sample in the morning.

Comment: I ran it in SSRs but no luck. Than you for your help! Please get some rest!

Comment: Alan, I would really appreciate it if you are able to help me.

Comment: I'll try to take a look tonight, no promises though!